# Force Spring Boot to override default configurations

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit, applicationcontext, testcontainers

I'm trying to implement the usage of **Testcontainers** as an alternative for IT test on a project, currently the project it's using H2 as datasource for testing, the matter is that no matter what I try I'm not able to override those configurations in order to create a custom datasource by using a DB container, what I've tried so far:

1. Setting the datasource attributes directly on the **application-testcontainers.yml** file + **@ActiveProfiles("testcontainers")** annotation.

```
    spring:
          datasource:
            url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/testcontainers
            username: user
            password: 123456

        
        @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
        @ActiveProfiles("testcontainers")
        public final class MyTestClass {
    
        }
```

3. Creating an extension class in order to set the datasource attributes (overriding the **beforeAll** method):

```
    public class TestcontainersExtension implements BeforeAllCallback, AfterAllCallback {
                        private PostgreSQLContainer<?> container;
                    
                        @Override
                        public void beforeAll(ExtensionContext context) throws Exception {
                            container = new PostgreSQLContainer<>("postgres:9.4")
                                    .withDatabaseName("testcontainers")
                                    .withUsername("user")
                                    .withPassword("123456")
                                    .withExposedPorts(5432);
                    
                            container.start();
                    
                            System.setProperty("spring.datasource.url", container.getJdbcUrl());
                            System.setProperty("spring.datasource.username", container.getUsername());
                            System.setProperty("spring.datasource.password", container.getPassword());
                        }
                    
                        @Override
                        public void afterAll(ExtensionContext context) throws Exception {
                    
                        }
                    }
                
                    @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
                    @ExtendWith(TestcontainersExtension.class)
                    public final class MyTestClass {
                    
                    }
```

4. Using **@DynamicPropertySource** method in order to set the configuration properties dynamically

```
     @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
        MyTestClass {
    
            @Container
            static PostgreSQLContainer<?> container = 
                    new PostgreSQLContainer<>("postgres:9.4")
                    .withDatabaseName("testcontainers")
                    .withUsername("user")
                    .withPassword("123456")
                    .withExposedPorts(5432);
    
            @DynamicPropertySource
            static void setTestProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {
                registry.add("spring.datasource.url", () -> container.getJdbcUrl());
        
                registry.add("spring.datasource.username", () -> container.getUsername());
                registry.add("spring.datasource.password", () -> container.getPassword());
            }
        }
```

5. **@ContextConfiguration** + an initializer class, also trying to set the properties dynamically

```
    @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
    @ContextConfiguration(initializers = {MyTestClass.Initializer.class})
    public final class MyTestClass {
        @Container
        static PostgreSQLContainer<?> container = 
                new PostgreSQLContainer<>("postgres:9.4")
                .withDatabaseName("testcontainers")
                .withUsername("user")
                .withPassword("123456")
                .withExposedPorts(5432);
    
        static class Initializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {
    
            @Override
            public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext) {
                TestPropertyValues.of(
                        "spring.datasource.url=" + container.getJdbcUrl(),
                        "spring.datasource.username=" + container.getUsername(),
                        "spring.datasource.password=" + container.getPassword()
                ).applyTo(applicationContext.getEnvironment());
            }
        }
    
    }
```

None of the above worked for me, I’ll appreciate any hint or alternative.

Comment: Can you please also share the error logs of each solution you tried? For solution 4) (DynanicProperySource) you seem to miss the `@Testcontainers` annotation to manage the lifecycle of your container. This [article](https://rieckpil.de/howto-write-spring-boot-integration-tests-with-a-real-database/) shows various integration methods for Spring Boot and JUnit 4/5 (make sure to check out the linked GitHub repo for working examples).